# Como converter Datetime para timestamp? (SQL SERVER)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hoje eu tenho a seguinte situação, necessito enviar a data atual e horário da requisição em um formato int, conforme imagem abaixo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Abaixo estão algumas tentativas que realizei, mas na hora de testar a conversão para date para validação do resultado, retornou uma data incoerente.

`cast(GETDATE() as bigint)`
 `CAST((convert(datetime,getdate(),108))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Experimente fazer uns testes com o script abaixo:

```
declare @DataIni datetime;
declare @Tempo int;
declare @Data datetime;

set @DataIni = dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, getutcdate(), getdate()), '19700101');

set @Data = '20210114 01:16:58';

set @Tempo = datediff(second, @DataIni, @Data);

select @Tempo, dateadd(second, @Tempo, @DataIni)
```

obs: 01/01/1970 UTC/GMT é a data inicial padrão para o cálculo

Espero que ajude

Comment: Imex, como eu consigo utilizar somente a coluna que retornou os dados inteiros? colocar um aliás para ela?

Comment: não sei se entendi corretamente, mas experimente algo como segue:  `select
  datediff
    (second, 
     dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, getutcdate(), getdate()), '19700101'), 
     getdate()) as Tempo`

Comment: Isso mesmo, perfeito!